# Umbrella term for economic, social, and demographic trends

Tags: adjectives, terminology, hypernyms

I am writing a cover letter for an application to an economic think tank that focuses on "how family and individual well-being is shaped by economic, social, and demographic trends." I want to describe my experience doing similar research using an umbrella term that encompasses "economic, social, and demographic trends."

Comment: socio-economic comes to mind.  demographic, separate.

Comment: One might surmise that if such a word existed the think tank would have used themselves.

Comment: Are 'social-economic trends' considered to be a type of demographic trend in your field?

Comment: i think that demographics are subsumed by socio-economic

Comment: socioeconomic trends will cover demographic trends.

Answer (score 1):

For an umbrella term that encompasses "economic, social, and demographic" trends, consider *[societal](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/societal)*:

> **societal**, *adj., formal*: relating to society or to the way that society is organized

So you would highlight your experience doing research into *societal* trends.

Here are articles that use *societal* in precisely that sense:

- *[An Analysis of Global Societal Trends to 2030 and Their Impact on the EU](https://www.rand.org/randeurope/research/projects/global-societal-trends.html)*
- *[13 Societal Trends](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/how-do-life/201708/13-societal-trends)*
- *[Ten Key Societal Trends For Market Researchers: Domestic and Global](https://www.decisionanalyst.com/whitepapers/futuretrends/)*

Comment: social and society are very different...

Comment: @Lambie see my expanded answer; _societal_ is commonly used in this context.

Comment: I am not convinced that societal encompasses demographics.

Answer (score 0):

**At the heart (of society)** *idiomatic*

*In the 1950's, blue jeans were **at the heart of** American society. Stores such as Sears were packed full of customers trying them on; anybody who was anybody wore them out to any social occasion short of a wedding; and there was no age, gender, or race who felt blue jeans were above or beneath them.*

This is different from "get to the heart of" which defines as: Find or determine the most important or essential facts or meaning. For example, It's important to get to the heart of the matter before we make any decisions. The noun heart has been used in the sense of "a vital part" since the early 1500s. [Dictionary.com]